# Ajax.IsAjaxRequest() always returns false?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In the controller class the code "if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())" always returns false... Can anyone help me figure it out? But if i use ajax.beginform in cshtml page and do not use the jquery file then it returns true.

This is my cshtml file

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")" data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#ListOfdata">
<input type="search" name="SearchTerm"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

This is my controller logic:

```
 public ActionResult Index( string SearchTerm)
    {
        var departments = db.Departments.Include(d => d.Administrator);
        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        { 
            if (SearchTerm != null)
            {
                 var departments2 = db.Departments.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(SearchTerm));
                 return PartialView("_Department", departments2.ToList());              
            }
        }
        return View(departments.ToList());
    }
```

And this is my jquery file to handle ajax request

```
$(function () {
var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
    var form = $(this);
    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()

    };
    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
        $target.replaceWith(data);
    });
    return false;
};

$("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit); });
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=isajaxrequest%20returns%20false

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js this will most likely solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is an Ajax header in the request:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

It's supposed to be there by default but for good measure:

```
header: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' }
```

If this header is set, `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` will work.

Comment: can you tell me where do i add that?

Comment: didn't help bro I added the header in all the possible ways I could, but had no effect in the execution.

Answer (score 0):

A probable cause is the wrong jquery version. Try using a newer version of jquery.